# Multipathd load balancing on md3200i

Tags: storage-area-network, centos5, iscsi, multipath

I'm working on setting up a cluster of servers with an iSCSI MD3200i SAN for shared storage. Everything is working well but I have one small detail I can't seem to get working. Multipath seems to only want to do failover with the iSCSI connections to the SAN. I'd like to get this working in load balancing mode so that it uses each path and not just one or the other.

One always shows as ghost here, meaning it's not being used.

```
[root@kvm-01]~# multipath -ll
mpath2 (36842b2b0006b9d87000004383bf558d9) dm-5 DELL,MD32xxi
[size=2.2T][features=3 queue_if_no_path pg_init_retries 50][hwhandler=1 rdac][rw]
\_ round-robin 0 [prio=100][active]
 \_ 8:0:0:0   sdb 8:16  [active][ready]
  \_ 7:0:0:0  sdc 8:32  [active][ghost]
```

My multipathd conf:

```
[root@kvm-01]~# egrep -v '(#|^$)' /etc/multipath.conf
blacklist {
        device {
                vendor  "*"
                product "Universal Xport"
        }
        device {
                vendor  "*"
                product "MD3000"
        }
        device {
                vendor  "*"
                product "MD3000i"
        }
        device {
                vendor  "*"
                product "Virtual Disk"
        }
devnode "^(ram|raw|loop|fd|md|dm-|sr|scd|st)[0-9]*"
devnode "^hd[a-z][[0-9]*]"
devnode "^cciss!c[0-9]d[0-9]*[p[0-9]*]"
devnode "^sda$"
}
defaults {
        user_friendly_names   yes
        polling_interval      5
        selector              "round-robin 0"
        path_checker          rdac
        path_grouping_policy  multibus
        rr_weight             uniform
        no_path_retry         30
        failback              immediate
        rr_min_io             100
        prio_callout          "/sbin/mpath_prio_rdac /dev/%n"
        max_fds               8192
}
devices {
        device {
                vendor                "DELL"
                product               "MD32xxi"
                hardware_handler      "1 rdac"
                features              "2 pg_init_retries 50"
        }
        device {
                vendor                "DELL"
                product               "MD32xx"
                hardware_handler      "1 rdac"
                features              "2 pg_init_retries 50"
        }
        device {
                vendor                "DELL"
                product               "MD36xxi"
                hardware_handler      "1 rdac"
                features              "2 pg_init_retries 50"
        }
}
```

I've tried a variety of group_by and rr_weight settings, all with the same result.

```
[root@kvm-01]~# lsmod | grep rdac
dm_rdac                41673  1
dm_multipath           58457  3 dm_round_robin,dm_rdac
scsi_mod              199001  14 dm_rdac,be2iscsi,ib_iser,iscsi_tcp,bnx2i,cxgb3i,libiscsi2,scsi_transport_iscsi2,scsi_dh,sr_mod,sg,libata,megaraid_sas,sd_mod
```

I've also tried loading scsi_dh_rdac by that didn't make a difference either.

```
[root@kvm-01]~# egrep -v '(#|^$)' /etc/iscsi/iscsid.conf
node.startup = automatic
node.session.timeo.replacement_timeout = 30
node.conn[0].timeo.login_timeout = 15
node.conn[0].timeo.logout_timeout = 15
node.conn[0].timeo.noop_out_interval = 5
node.conn[0].timeo.noop_out_timeout = 15
node.session.err_timeo.abort_timeout = 15
node.session.err_timeo.lu_reset_timeout = 20
node.session.initial_login_retry_max = 8
node.session.cmds_max = 128
node.session.queue_depth = 32
node.session.iscsi.InitialR2T = No
node.session.iscsi.ImmediateData = Yes
node.session.iscsi.FirstBurstLength = 262144
node.session.iscsi.MaxBurstLength = 16776192
node.conn[0].iscsi.MaxRecvDataSegmentLength = 262144
discovery.sendtargets.iscsi.MaxRecvDataSegmentLength = 32768
node.conn[0].iscsi.HeaderDigest = None
node.session.iscsi.FastAbort = No
node.session.xmit_thread_priority = -20
node.conn[0].iscsi.MaxXmitDataSegmentLength = 0
```

I've been researching this for awhile now, and I've found plenty of people getting this setup to work with a MD3000i, but no confirmation either way of the 3200i. I found one person saying it doesn't support it because the secondary controller is passive by design but I've been unable to confirm that in Dell's documentation.

```
[root@kvm-01]~# uname -a
Linux kvm-01 2.6.18-238.9.1.el5 #1 SMP Tue Apr 12 18:10:13 EDT 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 1):

### Summary

The only load balancing you can do is by spreading the LUNs amongst the controllers.
While it advertises itself as active-active it is actually a dual-active SAN. So a LUN may only be associated with at most one storage processor at any one time, yet both controllers can be active and drive LUNs dedicated to each controller. That's what's meant by Active/Active in this case, that SAN can be fully utilized, and not that a single LUN can be load balanced by two controllers at the same time.

### Details

Your path status for sdc says it all, **ghost == passive**, so all your
multipath configuration is good for is failover. Your configuration is
Active/Passive by definition.

http://sourceware.org/lvm2/wiki/MultipathUsageGuide

That standby storage controller needs be configured for Active/Active
mode to accomplish what you're after; It may be a limitation of the SAN.

### Verification

In answering a different question using the same SAN I discovered the docs for the SAN
on the web and verified that this make and model is in fact dual-active. See:

[Dell PowerVault MD3200i dm-multipath configuration and performance snags in Debian 6.0 (squeeze)](https://serverfault.com/questions/351638/dell-powervault-md3200i-dm-multipath-configuration-and-performance-snags-in-debi/359996#359996)

Comment: According to [link](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pvaul/en/powervault-md3200i-md3220i-technical-guidebook-en.pdf) -- "MD3200i dual controller model – Dual, active/active controllers"

Comment: Well, it's not behaving like one. So it's either SAN side configuration or some subtle multipath issue, maybe even a bug. It's basic troubleshooting at this point, the user just needs to run it down.

Comment: +1 - This is all accurate. A LUN can be owned by only one controller at a time. You can spread LUNs across both controllers but you can't load-balance a LUN across both.

Answer (score 1):

MD3200i (as well as every other LSI rebrand) uses RDAC. That's an a/p algorithm.