# Dell PowerVault MD3200i dm-multipath configuration and performance snags in Debian 6.0 (squeeze)

Tags: debian, dell, iscsi, multipath

I'll be using this iSCSI target for a couple of Debian-based KVM virtual machine hosts. Each of the target's redundant controllers has 4 ethernet ports; likewise for the initiators. I use two switches (ZyXEL GS-2200-24) with a trunk between them, and VLANs isolate each path. I've also enabled jumbo frames and flow control.

The MPIO system in this Debian release is fabulous: as long as dm-multipath is loaded before logging in to the iSCSI target, everything Just Works<sup>TM</sup> without any configuration file, provided I load scsi_dh_rdac before-hand.

That's the first snag: I can change some of the defaults if I provide an `/etc/multipath.conf` file.  I tested with `use_friendly_names yes`, which successfully creates an `mpath0` link in `/dev/mapper/` – instead of using the unfriendly-looking WWID.  But if I try to change `rr_min_io` from the default 1000 down to 8, I get ignored; so I do this pretty dance:

```
dmsetup suspend mpath0
dmsetup table mpath0 | sed 's, 1000, 8,g' | dmsetup reload mpath0
dmsetup resume mpath0
```

That changes the number of requests sent down one of the quad links before round-robin kicks in and sends it down the next, from the default 1000 down to 8. This actually changes the multipath table (as per `multipath -v3 | grep params`). How does one configure this default in the new multipath code? I'm assuming this worked before multipath went all dynamic and self-configuring... At least all vendor docs I've read, and other discussions on the web kind of assume this worked.

A simple sequential write using `dd bs=100M count=50 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mapper/mpath0-part1 & sync` goes from ~135MB/s up to ~260MB/s with this change. And that's the second snag: that's about 2Gbps instead of the 4Gbps I actually have between the initiator and the target. Running `iostat -kd 1` for 1sec running updates shows only 2 of the 4 paths being filled up.

This LUN is short-stroked: its 16GB reside right at the beginning of a 12-spindle RAID10 array of 600 6Gbps SAS disks spinning at 15,000rpm. I was expecting this to be enough to saturate the 4Gbps I have; am I correct?

Comment: Have you tried running several `dd` commands in parallel? Might show different results, and will better simulate real VM loads. And if you want to get even closer you could use SpecVIRT's benchmarks.

Comment: Good idea; I ran two in parallel and got a severe increase in performance for one of them, while the second one had approximately the same running time. I guess one of them was benefiting from write-cache.

Comment: Funny thing is that `iostat -kd 1` still showed only 2 of 4 pipes being near 100MB/s.

Let me just add that at this point I want to saturate the links: until I get near the 500MB/s mark, there's not much point in fiddling with the rest. As far as I can see, the best way to fill all links is to reduce the round-robin down to a very small number like 1, 3 or 5.

And I still haven't found a way to persist these configuration changes in a way that a configuration reload via `multipath -r` doesn't return to `round-robin` with a `rr_min_io` of 1000!

Comment: I don't think 1000 is so bad, it's a number of IOs, not bytes after all. Besides, to do disk benchmarking, bonnie++ is the right solution, if you want to avoid using a full fledged benchmark suite.

Comment: BTW, another place you can try tweaking is iscsi.conf

Comment: Problem is that two competing `dd` still don't use more than just the two cables at the same time. And that's more like one cable handing off to the next one, like passing the baton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Online Reconfiguration

The technique you used to change the `rr_min_io` is what multipathd does for you under the covers. The user friendly way to adjust  values in a running map is `echo reconfigure | multipathd -k`

For example: Here's a NetApp who's `rr_min_io` is currently 128

```
# dmsetup table
360a98000534b504d6834654d53793373: 0 33484800 multipath 0 1 alua 2 1 round-robin 0 2 1 8:16 128 8:32 128 round-robin 0 2 1 8:64 128 8:48 128 
360a98000534b504d6834654d53793373-part1: 0 33484736 linear 251:0 64
```

`/etc/multipath.conf` was changed so `rr_min_io` was now `1000`. Then,

```
# echo reconfigure | multipathd -k
multipathd> reconfigure
ok
```

To verify the change:

```
# dmsetup table
360a98000534b504d6834654d53793373: 0 33484800 multipath 0 1 alua 2 1 round-robin 0 2 1 8:16 1000 8:32 1000 round-robin 0 2 1 8:48 1000 8:64 1000 
360a98000534b504d6834654d53793373-part1: 0 33484736 linear 251:0 64
```

I agree multipathd could do a better job in advertising and reporting the additional variables it uses. Whatever delta multipathd doesn't report, dmsetup does, but that doesn't necessarily mean that using dmsetup directly is the best idea to reconfigure those settings. Reconfigure works for just about everything.

### Active-Active load balancing

The deployment guide says your SAN is active-active but this term gets misused in the industry, in practice it can be "dual active", which means a LUN can only be accessed by a single storage processor at any one time, but both controllers can be active and drive distinct LUNs, they just can't load balance to the same lun.

[Here on p79](http://www.manualowl.com/m/Dell/PowerVault-MD3200i/Manual/190070) under the load balancing section.

```
Two sessions with one TCP connection are configured from the host to each controller (one
 session per port), for a total of four sessions. The multi-path failover driver balances 
I/O access across the sessions to the ports on the same controller. In a duplex 
configuration, with virtual disks on each controller, creating sessions using each of the 
iSCSI data ports of both controllers increases bandwidth and provides load balancing
```

Note the plural use of **virtual disks** in the context of **duplex configuration**, it doesn't call out the same disk. This appears to be an dual-active deployment. True active-active SANs are usually reserved for Fibre Channel deployments. Maybe iSCSI SANs exist that accomplish this, I haven't come across one, though I don't extensively deploy iSCSI either.

Comment: I can confirm that "active-active" here means ALUA. As per reconfigure in multipathd, see below. Please do add the values which have given you most performance; I was surprised to see that I had to go down to 3 (where you've got 128) to get full quad-pipe utilization.

Comment: ALUA isn't all that it's cracked up to be, you're utilizing a bus interconnect between the two storage processors to achieve asymmetric access to the LUN, which could crowd out IO to LUNs assigned to that other controller to begin with.

Comment: There's no magic queue depth number, it's set in concert with storage queue and parameter tuning for the entire storage stack. You have to first decide what's more important to you, response time or throughput. Only you know what your VM loads are like, create a stimulus model e.g guest benchmarks, and then systematically measure and tune each parameter accordingly. There are lots of SAN articles on setting queue depth, for example: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/joe_chang/archive/2010/10/18/io-queue-depth-strategy.aspx, yes it's windows specific but the general concepts still hold. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The real problem behind the ignored value rr_min_io is a simple and silent ABI mismatch between the running kernel and the multipath-tools.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on that? Seeing that you're running Debian I suspect it to be difficult to apt-get install the wrong packages, which would imply you found a bug. Did you file one yet?

Comment: I suspect it was caused by having the initiator installed with a Debian Squeeze, later upgrading it to Wheezy, and I had Squeeze as the preferred distribution. I'll have to find the exact versions in Wheezy which broke the ABI.